# wrong version number error while trying to write into SQL through python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a python code which writes data into an mysql database into different tables every 1 minute(for stock trading). The issues, the mysql writing works fine for sometime and I can see the entries in the respective table, but then I start seeing below kind of error message after sometime.

Can someone guide me on how I can clear this issue? And why is it happening, any sources I can look into?

MySql connection establishment code

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="password123",
    database="testdb"
)

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
```

the line at which the error is getting triggered

```
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + str(
                trd_portfolio[company_data['instrument_token']]['Symbol']) + "_ohlc_final_1min values (\"" + str(
                ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][0]) + "\",\"" + str(ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][1]) + "\"," + str(
                ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][2]) + "," + str(ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][3]) + "," + str(
                ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][4]) + "," + str(ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][5]) + "," + str(
                ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][6]) + "," + str(ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][7]) + "," + str(
                ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][8]) + "," + str(ohlc[company_data['instrument_token']][9]) + ")")
            mydb.commit()
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-679:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 265, in recv_plain
    chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
  File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1056, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 931, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)
```

Comment: Please include the python code where you are seeing this error. That message typically means you are using the wrong port but without seeing your code, I'm only guessing.

Comment: i have updated the quetion @SamM